# firefox browser detection using javascript

Tags: firefox

I have a javascript based web app and I want it must run in firefox(any version). i have gone through several solutions including navigator object, browserversion specific object detection etc,  but no one helped. kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zxvE/383/